# Making nested request calls in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping, request, async-await

As the title says, I am trying to make a nested request call, where the first request grabs an img src from a page's html, and then passes that src into another request.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

async function main() {
    for (let i = 1; i < 1061; i++) {
        let url = `https://manuals.co/workshop/volkswagen/corrado/volkswagen-corrado-1990-1994-workshop-manual/5874057/${i}`

        await getSrc(url, i)
    }
}

async function getSrc(uri, j) {
    request(uri, function(error, response, html) {
        let $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const imgSrc = $('.bi.x0.y0.w0.h1').attr("src")
        console.log(imgSrc)
        request(imgSrc).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`images/test-${j}.png`)).on('close', function() {
            console.log(`Completed image number: ${j}`)
        })
    })
}

main()
```

When I run this, 'imgSrc' is logged to the console as 'undefined' and I get the error:

```
Error: undefined is not a valid uri or options object.
```

I've tried using await as follows:

```
const imgSrc = await $('.bi.x0.y0.w0.h1').attr("src")
```

In this case, I get the error 'Unexpected Idendifier' on that line.
I will also point out that when I run the getSrc function on its own (not in a for loop), it works as expected.  I am at a loss as to what is causing it to break when placed in a loop.

I am very new to node.js and asynchronous programming, so what I am looking for is a solution that can help me understand the way this stuff works.

Comment: do `console.log(html)` before cheerio.load

Comment: It's considered annoying to add "I am new to..." to question, see  [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950). As long as you follow the rules in [help], it's fine.

Comment: a console.log(html) occasionally will log a few html pages to the console before the code breaks

Answer (score 0):

Try running it synchronously. Remove `async` and `await` and see if you still get that error. If you still do it's likely `$('.bi.x0.y0.w0.h1').attr("src")` really returns undefined.